# Plotting complex value on an Argand diagram

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function, graphing-functions

How would I plot $e^{(i (\frac{1}{2}+2k))}$ where $k \in \Bbb Z$ my initial thought would that it would just be points on the imaginary axis but now for some reason I'm thinking that it could be a circle but I'm unsure what the radius should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

radius is $r=1$ as general form is $z=re^{i\theta}$ In your plot the angle is $\theta=\frac12+2k$ and the plot is like the one in the picture below

Hope this helps

$$...$$

[image]

Comment: Is the general form you stated that of a circle as you can write it in terms of sin and cosine?

Comment: @Gibberish It's not necessary: $z=e^{i\theta}$ is already a circle having radius $r=1$.

Comment: Oh okay do all the points lie on the circumstance ?& is there any need for a line through the points ?

Comment: Yes they do. They are *dense* on the circumference  when $k$ varies from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$

Comment: Ok brilliant, if I was to have e^kπ this would just be values on the positive real axis as there is no imaginary value ?

Comment: Yes. $e^{k\pi};\;k\in\mathbb{Z}$ are real positive values which "accumulate" near $0$ as $k\to-\infty$ and become exponentially far from origin as $k\to +\infty$